# Не срабатывает Replace() в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу все пробелы в Number заменить на нили, но REPLACE почему то не срабатывает.

```
PRINT 'unchanged Number @Number: ' + @Number
SELECT REPLACE('@Number', ' ', '0');
PRINT 'changed Number @Number: ' + @Number
```

В PRINT, до изменений и после Number одинаковый.

Использую SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

Comment: Дружище, ты меняешь не в переменной `@Number`, а в строковом литерале `'@Number'`. И в нём, вообще-то, пробелов нет у прынципе. Ног даже и если бы там была переменная - её-то значение меняется НЕ ТАК... `SET` надобен.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию @Akina исправил код на этот.

```
PRINT 'unchanged Number @Number: ' + @Number
SET @Number = REPLACE(@Number  , ' ', '0');
PRINT 'changed Number @Number: ' + @Number
```